# Nominatim: osm2pgsql path specification problem

Tags: nominatim

**The Problem:**

I've installed Nominatim on CentOS 7, but I'm running into an import error when I try to load the data. Here is the error:

```
Import
Please download and build osm2pgsql.
If it is already installed, check the path in your local settings  (settings/local.php) file.
ERROR: osm2pgsql not found in '/opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql'
osm2pgsql not found in '/opt/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql'
```

Osm2pgsql is already installed and here are the following paths after I run some find commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql
/usr/local/share/osm2pgsql
```

I've tried specifying these paths in the local.php file like this:

```
@define('CONST_Osm2pgsql', '/usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql');
@define('CONST_Osm2pgsql', '/usr/local/share/osm2pgsql');
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same problem, so I must not be specifying the paths right. Does anyone know the syntax of local.php? There aren't any guides I could find online beyond basic postgresql and postgis configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `which` command to verify the correct path of the osm2pgsql binary:

```
which osm2pgsql
```

And try to use `@define('CONST_Osm2pgsql_Binary', '/usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql');`  instead of `@define('CONST_Osm2pgsql', '/usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql');`